# Keep dimension of new image when replacing old image using docx4j

Tags: java, image, docx4j

I need to add an image to my `docx` file. The image is a `png` image of a signature that is to placed behind text in the signature line of a certificate to be downloaded by the user as a `docx`, a `pdf` or `jpg`. The first problem I encountered is that you can only add inline image using the latest version of docx4j (v6.1.2) and creating an image `Anchor` is currently disabled (see [BinaryPartAbstractImage.java: line 1029](https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/src/main/java/org/docx4j/openpackaging/parts/WordprocessingML/BinaryPartAbstractImage.java)). That's a problem since the signature image is not inline, it supposed to appear behind the name on the signature line. Instead of inserting one myself, my workaround is to place a placeholder image:

[image]

These images are mapped as `image1.png` and `image2.png`, respectively, on `/word/media` directory of the `docx` uncompressed version. The program then replaces these with the name, position, and actual `png` of the signature every time a certificate is generated.

[image]

The problem is that the images are scaled the same dimension as the placeholder image, where in fact it should look like this:

[image]

How can I get to keep the image dimension of the image after replacing, or at least the aspect ratio? Here is how I replace the placeholder image with the new image:

```
File approveBySignatureImage = new File(...);
final String approvedByImageNodeId = "rId5";

replaceImageById(approvedByImageNodeId,
    "image1.png", approveBySignatureImage);
```

This is the actual method where the replacing happens:

```
public void replaceImageById(String id, String placeholderImageName, File newImage) throws Exception {
    Relationship rel = document.getMainDocumentPart().getRelationshipsPart().getRelationshipByID(id);

    BinaryPartAbstractImage imagePart;
    if(FilenameUtils.getExtension(placeholderImageName).toLowerCase() == ContentTypes.EXTENSION_BMP) {
        imagePart = new ImageBmpPart(new PartName("/word/media/" + placeholderImageName));
    }
    else if([ContentTypes.EXTENSION_JPG_1, ContentTypes.EXTENSION_JPG_2].contains(FilenameUtils.getExtension(placeholderImageName).toLowerCase())) {
        imagePart = new ImageJpegPart(new PartName("/word/media/" + placeholderImageName));
    }
    else if(FilenameUtils.getExtension(placeholderImageName).toLowerCase() == ContentTypes.EXTENSION_PNG) {
        imagePart = new ImagePngPart(new PartName("/word/media/" + placeholderImageName));
    }

    InputStream stream = new FileInputStream(newImage);
    imagePart.setBinaryData(stream);

    if(FilenameUtils.getExtension(newImage.getName()).toLowerCase() == ContentTypes.EXTENSION_BMP) {
        imagePart.setContentType(new ContentType(ContentTypes.IMAGE_BMP));
    }
    else if([ContentTypes.EXTENSION_JPG_1, ContentTypes.EXTENSION_JPG_2].contains(FilenameUtils.getExtension(newImage.getName()).toLowerCase())) {
        imagePart.setContentType(new ContentType(ContentTypes.IMAGE_JPEG));
    }
    else if(FilenameUtils.getExtension(newImage.getName()).toLowerCase() == ContentTypes.EXTENSION_PNG) {
        imagePart.setContentType(new ContentType(ContentTypes.IMAGE_PNG));
    }

    imagePart.setRelationshipType(Namespaces.IMAGE);

    final String embedId = rel.getId();

    rel = document.getMainDocumentPart().addTargetPart(imagePart);
    rel.setId(embedId);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to set the dimensions (or possibly just remove what you have?) on your placeholder image.

For help in doing that:-

docx4j inspects the image to work that out at https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/src/main/java/org/docx4j/openpackaging/parts/WordprocessingML/BinaryPartAbstractImage.java#L512 using org.apache.xmlgraphics ImageInfo.

See also CxCy:https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/src/main/java/org/docx4j/openpackaging/parts/WordprocessingML/BinaryPartAbstractImage.java#L1164

https://github.com/plutext/docx4j/blob/master/src/main/java/org/docx4j/openpackaging/parts/WordprocessingML/BinaryPartAbstractImage.java#L815 shows scaling to maintain aspect ratio.